# No-nonsense mp3 player for Mac?

Tags: osx, audio, music, media-player, mp3

Looking for a nice, simple, user friendly, no-nonsense mp3 player for Mac. Or actually, not specific mp3 but just a general audio / music player.

I hate iTunes. I want something that doesn't force me to categorize my music in libraries, or keep it in certain folders, or import my music files before I can play them, or keep track of whatever. No music 'manager'.

I just want something that plays audio files, simple as that. Preferably open source and/or something that can be installed through Homebrew (or Caskroom).

Any recommendations?

Comment: I think maybe irfanview would work.  It was originally just for images but I think you can play audio files with it too.

Comment: @aparente001 Do you mean irfanview.com or something else? Because that seems like a Windows application.

Comment: Oh.  I just realized I was confusing irfanview and notepad++.  Sorry, I didn't realize irfanview isn't cross-platform.

Answer (score 4):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/) is the best for your requirement

Doesn't ask for any **"Import"** or **"Creating Music Libraries"**

Comment: Please remove the Clementine part or make it a separate answer, thanks :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I have just added [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/) because its another music-player which is a open source and similar to VLC and I have used it, Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks! The question says "Preferably open source and/or something that can be installed through Homebrew (or Caskroom)", I know you can make your answer even better by detailing how it fits the open source requirement, at least. Also, your answer would be nicer with a screenshot, and saying the price.

Answer (score 1):

## [C* Music Player](https://cmus.github.io#features)

- **User-friendly?** It is command-line tool, so Maybe
- **Simple?** Yes
- **Manage Music?** No
- **Homebrew?** [No](https://github.com/cmus/cmus#installation), but it is open source

  - **Mac?** Yes

In Cmus you directly browse the file system so you are free to organize your audio files however you like. Cmus also has several [extensions](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/wiki) for adding more functionality (eg lyric viewing with lyvi).

[image: pic from their website]

Comment: Thanks, command line was actually not was I was looking for, but C* Player definitely looks like an interesting alternative